# Tell Windows 7: "This is a thethering WLAN, allow only Browser and skype to use it."

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, tethering, limited-access

Is there some software that can be configured to recognize certain WLAN SSIDs as tethering connection and block all traffic from programs other than those explicitly added to a whitelist?

I know that it should in theory be possible using just the Windows firewall; If I'd find that a satisfactory solution, I would consider my question a clear duplicate.

Considering though how quickly a 1GB/mth volume can be exceeded when Steam starts downloading some update, I'd rather prefer a special-purpose program that makes the task easy and misconfiguration unlikely. Ideally there should be a taskbar icon indicating that the limitation rule has been enacted, similiar to Nvidia optimus indicating dedicated graphics activity.

Comment: Not only does Steam uses HTTP for some file transfers, but also Browser-only traffic can reach 1GB very easily. I would personally use a firewall software such as Netlimiter to block/limit per-process bandwidth when using those connections. But it won't automatically switch from a profile to another depeding on wireless SSID connected to...

Answer (score 0):

This is easily controlled by a windows firewall policy, by setting block as the default setting to outbound connections.

You would need to set the 'Public' profile for this setting. Doing this you loose the ability to use the public profile for other connections.

It may be easier to just block steam on the profile, rather than block everything and allow only the browser and skype.

Comment: Would this method prevent e.g. Windows Update from downloading patches while tethered and can it be set to recognize only specific wireless networks? Anyway, the blacklist approach is *not* viable, since an error in the setup potentially causes high cost or at least consumption of the full-speed quota.

Comment: With block by default you can whitelist the windows update service, and other update services, say antimalware programs for example.